# on JQuery Deffered object (with backboneJS) how do i know which request failed?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I tried doing this with backboneJS:

```
$.when(cardsCollection.fetch(),series.fetch())
              .done(function(){
                cardsListView.series = series;
                cardsListView.template = _.template(CardsListTemplate);
                cardsListView.render();
            }).fail(function(){
                cardsListView.series = new Series({seriesID:0,seriesName:""});
                cardsListView.template = _.template(CardsListTemplate);
                cardsListView.render();
                });
```

I am missing the fail callback arguments in the example.
however, my intent is to check which fetch failed and if it was the series go on with fake data.

is it possible with JQuery deffered?

Comment: Try console.logging the arguments passed to `.fail()` to see if there is any useful information in them. `console.log(arguments)`

Comment: that's the weird part. i tried logging both the done and the fail arguments. it goes to fail only and has only the arguments of fail...

Comment: Also try `.always`, just to be thorough. it works the same way as `.done` and `.fail`, console.log the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [deferred.state()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/)

```
 cardsCollectionPromise = cardsCollection.fetch();
 seriesPromise = series.fetch();
 $.when(cardsCollectionPromise, seriesPromise)
          .done(function(){
        // ...
        }).fail(function(){
            if (cardsCollectionPromise.state() === 'rejected') {
               // ...
            },
            else (seriesPromise.state() === 'rejected') {
              // ...
            }
            });
```